# Python : Comparing two times, and returning in minutes

Tags: python, string, class, date, time

I have a method which takes two strings (times) e.g. `15:01`
The method should take the times and do `time1-time2` and return to me a new time in minutes.
eg. `15:53 - 15:59` should give me `6 minutes` however i'm stuck.

This is my code:

```
import datetime 
class timeCalc(object):
    def timeDiff(self,time1,time2):
        timeA = datetime.datetime.strptime(time1, "%H:%M")
        timeB = datetime.datetime.strptime(time2, "%H:%M")
        newTime = timeA - timeB
```

Comment: Why are you stuck? What does `newTime` give you? What happens when you explore the methods available on that object? (And why are you defining a class here - why isn't `timeDiff` just a function?)

Comment: it gives me the result in a very weird format. I want the difference in minutes, then when I go to print in the console, it throws up an error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You function needs to `return` `newTime`:

```
import datetime

def timeDiff(time1,time2):
    timeA = datetime.datetime.strptime(time1, "%H:%M")
    timeB = datetime.datetime.strptime(time2, "%H:%M")
    newTime = timeA - timeB
    return newTime.seconds/60   

print timeDiff('15:59','15:53'), 'minutes'

>>> 6 minutes
```

Notes:

I think you want `newTime = timeB - timeA` otherwise you have to pass the times in *backwards* like I did.

Comment: To get the answer in minutes you should return `newTime.seconds/60` instead.

Comment: Thanks @olofom added it to my answer +1